# How to create directory in android 11 and above like Telegram

Tags: android, storage, android-11, scoped-storage, create-directory

I am trying to create a folder in device internal storage like the same way telegram and WhatsApp does in Android  11 and above devices without using manage access all files permission.  any reference on how to achieve this.. ?

Comment: Please tell full path of their directories.

Comment: You can write without permission media files to dir picture and DCIM

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Telegram   @blackapps

Comment: And for WhatApp?

Comment: @blackapps I check again for WhatsApp they are storing their files in Android / media / com.whatsapp

Comment: That is no full path. Please give full path like you did with Telegram.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp   @blackapps

Answer (score 0):

For Android 11+.

For the Telegram style one use SAF. For instance ACTION_DOCUMENT_TREE and let the user create the directory.

For a folder like whatsapp just use mkdirs().